# Modifying mongoose document on pre hook of findOneAndUpdate()

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a mongoose schema as such

```
var schema = new Schema({
    id:Number
    updated_at:Date
});
```

I am using `findOneAndUpdate()` to update this model as such

```
model.findOneAndUpdate(
    { id: json.id },
    json,
    {
        upsert: true,
        runValidators: true
    })
    .then(() => {
        recordsUpdated++;
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        this.emit('error', err);
    });
```

The value being passed in `json` is not correct and I need to make some modifications to it. I am looking for a pre hook to do the modification. I have tried

```
faction.pre('findOneAndUpdate', function (next) {
   this.update({ $set: { updated_at: this.getUpdate().updated_at * 1000 } });
   next();
});
```

In short I want to convert the timestamp which is in seconds to milliseconds before updating the database, but this doesn't work.

Comment: Seems wrong to do this in middleware rather than fixing up `json` before calling `findOneAndUpdate`: `json.updated_at *= 1000;`

Comment: Might be. This particular use case can be done without middleware. Still, it would be great to know how to achieve this process.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

After blindly throwing stones all around, what worked for me was

```
schema.pre('findOneAndUpdate', function (next) {
    this._update.updated_at *= 1000;
    next();
});
```

In short one needs to modify the document present in the `_update` property.

Comment: I will wait for other answers that might be better than mine

Comment: is this still valid in 2019 ? @Sayak

Comment: @SumeetKumar depends on the MongoDB and mongoose versions I guess. I wouldn't know since I don't use this anywhere anymore.

Comment: i've gone through document looking for something useful but no success also not able to find anything saying `this._update` property contain document

Comment: @SumeetKumar I remember not finding this in the documentation. I had to manually check the content of the objects and figure out stuff. Its possible that things have changed with the newer versions. I suggest to attempt this and if unsuccessful try to look what the `this` object contains in the hook and proceed from there.

Answer (score 0):

Better solution is like this:

```
schema.pre('findOneAndUpdate', function (this, next) {
    this.update().updated_at *= 1000;
    next();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update "mongoose": "^6.4.0"**

Thanks to the above top-rated solution, what worked for me was

```
this._update.$set.updated_at = new Date();
```

In my case, I wanted to save the `currency` key as uppercase if it is available in the requested object.

```
schema.pre('findOneAndUpdate', async function (next) {
  const currency = this?._update?.$set?.currency;
  if (currency) {
    this.set({ currency: currency.toUpperCase() });
  }
  next();
});
```